# Why is MetadataExchangeClient not working in Powershell?

Tags: wcf, powershell-3.0

I am trying to do the following:

```
$basicHttpBinding = New-Object System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding([System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode]::TransportCredentialOnly);
$basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = [System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType]::Windows;
$basicHttpBinding.MaxBufferSize = 65536000;
$basicHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536000;
$basicHttpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288;
$basicHttpBinding.CloseTimeout = "01:01:00";
$basicHttpBinding.OpenTimeout = "01:01:00";
$basicHttpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = "01:01:00";
$basicHttpBinding.SendTimeout = "01:01:00";
$mexClient = New-Object System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient($basicHttpBinding);
$mexClient.MaximumResolvedReferences = [System.Int32]::MaxValue
$metadataSet = $mexClient.GetMetadata([Uri]$WsdlUrl, $mode)
```

It appears that for whatever reason, the MexClient is not passing the credentials.  I say this because when I browse the $WsdlUrl in IE running as the same user as the script, I can see the wsdl just fine.  When I run the code above, I get an exception:

> Exception calling "GetMetadata" with "2" argument(s): "Metadata contains a reference that 
>                           cannot be resolved: 'http_://myServer:myPort/myVirtualDirectory/myWcfService.svc?wsdl'." ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Metadata contains a 
>                           reference that cannot be resolved: 'http_://myServer:myPort/myVirtualDirectory/myWcfService.svc?wsdl'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote 
>                           server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

---

### Edit 01

It also appears the the MetadataExchangeClient is not transmitting the request through http.  When I use fiddler there is not 'request' being sent, only an HTTP response of the failure.  How can I get the MexClient to send and receive via http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing:

```
$mexClient.HttpCredentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Before my GetMetaData call.  I thought the binding requirements were enough to clue in the MexClient that it should pass the default credentials, but that kind of intelligence was too optimistic.  Hope this helps someone.